# jquery Plugin Missing Element Context

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm creating a jquery plugin using the official [plugin guide](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/). My basic code looks like this:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.categories = function(options) {

        var settings = $.extend({
            ...
        }, options);

        var init = function()
        {
            // `this` is undefined here 
        };

        // `this` points to $("#pick-category") here
        init();
        return this;
    };
}( jQuery ));

// usage
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#pick-category").categories();
});
```

My problem is that in the context of the function `$.fn.categories`, `this` is defined and indeed referring to the `$(#pick-category)` jquery object. But in the context of the `init` function, which is called from the `$.fn.categories` function, `this` reports as `undefined`.

My question is, what is going on here? How does the context get lost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`init` is defined as a local variable which happens to be a function. It has no context, except what you give it. It is not related to the parent function it was declared within.

So give it a context using `call()`:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.categories = function(options) {

        var settings = $.extend({
            ...
        }, options);

        // define a local function unrelated to $.fn.categories or any other context
        var init = function()
        {
            // `this` is now $("#pick-category")
        };

        // `this` points to $("#pick-category") here

        // call the function with an explicit context
        init.call(this);

        return this;
    };
}( jQuery ));
```